# UIPickerView with details

Tags: ios, uipickerview, uipickerviewdatasource

I would like to know of the best way to handle adding a detail colum or extra component to handle adding details for each row.

I have a UI PickerView with an array of numbers to populate it but next to the numbers I would like to have details that is left alinged so it looks clean.

I have looked into multiple components to do this however scrolling them at the same time seems almost impossible.

is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: With a UIPickerView, you can have one component and return a custom view (containing the number and details) for each row using the [viewForRow delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006924-CH3-SW2).  A UITableView with custom cells or UITableViewCellStyleValue2 is another option.

Comment: UITableView is a brillian idea.. thanks